# polynomial $Q$ which satisfies certain condition

Tags: polynomials

Let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree $k$ such that $$Q(n) = {k + 1 \choose n }^{-1}$$ for $n=0, 1, \ldots k$. Find $Q(n + 1)$.

I have been working with interpolating polynomials and other numerical methods but I have no idea where to begin solving this problem? If anyone has any tips, they are highly appreciated!

Comment: Interpolating polynomials is exactly what you need. What do you know about them?

Comment: I know that if we have some points $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ and $f(x_0),\ldots,f(x_n)$ then I can use the Lagrange polynomials or the Newton method with divided differences to compute this interpolating polynomial.

Comment: Can you see what Lagrange gives when $k=1$ or $k=2$ already?

Comment: Hmm not directly.. can you explain a bit more? @ArnaudMortier

Comment: Interpolating polynomials is eactly what you should avoid to solve this problem. Since you need the value of $Q$ at an specific point, what you need is an [efficient algorithm to evaluate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville's_algorithm) $Q$ at $n+1$. You don't need to compute $Q$ for that.

Comment: @totoro what does this algorithm do exactly?

Comment: @mandella The algorithm evaluates the interpolating polynomial at a point, which is what you are being asked to do. Follow the link. In the article you will see the steps to run it.

Comment: @totoro I have read the article and the steps but still, I do not understand. Do I get a specific formula or what?

Comment: I get $Q(n+1)=\sum_{m=0}^{k}\sum_{r=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-r}\binom{m}{r}\binom{k+1}{r}^{-1}\binom{n+1}{m}$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got that? @totoro